# Bohr–Mollerup theorem for $x\gt 1$

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function

The Bohr–Mollerup theorem states that $f(x)=\int_{0}^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\, dt$ is the only function on $x\gt 0$ such that the following conditions are satisfied simultaneously:

1. $f(1)=1,$
2. $\forall x\gt 0:\, f(x+1)=xf(x),$
3. $\forall x\gt 0: f(x)$ is logarithmically convex.

But is $f(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\, dt$ the only function on $x\ge 1$ such that

1. $f(1)=1,$
2. $\forall x\gt 1:\, f(x+1)=xf(x),$
3. $\forall x\gt 1: f(x)$ is logarithmically convex?

If not, what would be a counterexample?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you are asking? Do you want to replace both $\forall x > 0$ by $\forall x > 1$? Are you asking about it being the only function on $(1,\infty)$ or $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, replace both. I will edit the question.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, you should specify the domain of the function, otherwise your question is meaningless.

Comment: @Klaus See my new edit.

Comment: In the standard [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem) of the theorem you just have to replace the interval $(0,1]$ with the interval $(1,2]$.

Comment: It seems the answer is "yes". If $\widetilde f$ is a function satisfying your conditions on $[1,\infty[$ then it seems the continuation of $\widetilde f$ to $]0,\infty[$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{\widetilde f(x)}x$ for $x<1$ and $f(x)=\widetilde f(x)$ for $x\geq1$ satisfies the Bohr–Mollerup conditions. ("Seems" because I am not sure if log-convexity is preserved.)